# What's the node.js memory breakdown?

Tags: node.js, memory, heap-memory

We are deploying a Node.js application. This app seems to be consuming way more RSS memory than it should. So we started to dive into things and we found the following, thanks to  `process.memoryUsage();`

- The RSS memory grows quickly to about 400MB and stays more or less stable in a 400MB-500MB, with small ups and small downs (Garbage collector running?)
- The heapUsed quickly grows to 50MB and then stays at that level (between 20MB and 100MB).
- The heaptotal is always about 30MB more MB than the heapUsed.

As you see there is a huge difference between the heap and the RSS, which is where I think we should focus. There doesn't seem to be any very significant leak in our heap.

Now, what's in RSS that is not in the heap? I believe C extensions, and Buffers, right? If so, how can we debug that. What else should we look for?

Comment: You don't state a problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to know the breakdown of the memory consumed by a node.js application, specifically why there is such a difference between the heap size and RSS consumption.

Comment: Yes, but to what purpose? Does this situation represent a problem for your code or are you simply curious? I ask because I'm not sure under what circumstances this might be a problem other than running node on a system with limited memory.

Comment: We have this app and it's clearly wasting our resources. We want to make better use of them.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's a param that can be passed to V8 via node at runtime to change the RSS

Comment: Have you looked into /proc/$PID/maps which kinds of memory areas are used?

Comment: @don_jones Not sure how to interpret the result. Anything I should be looking for specifically.

Comment: If memory indicators does not goes up indefinitely while your app is handling requests constantly then you do not have a memory leak. You are just seeing all the needed memory required to run your server.

Are you using some C libraries (some C compiled node-modules?).

Comment: @vvo the only C librairies we use are Hiredis and node-expat. So that must be buffers. But then, how can we find them (as they're out of the heap!)

Comment: So we had similar problem (objects that cannot be inspected using regular tools along with a growing RSS). So we ended up removing features after features (starting with the most suspicious ones) and testing when does the RSS stays low. Slow, time consuming but works. Again, if RSS stays at 400MB and do not grows constantly, buy a bigger server..

Comment: @vvo it grows 'weirdly', it's now at almost 1GB on a server running for an hour... I'll try the removing feature option to see which ones create Buffers. I wish there was better tools though.

Comment: Start with all modules (even core modules) handling big strings/buffers around (computing them, passing them, altering them). And share the results here! :) Good luck

Comment: @vvo Out of curiosity, since you had the same issue, what module was creasting a lot of buffers in your case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18849/discussion-between-vvo-and-julien-genestoux)

Comment: Nodejs folks should definitively update the documentation because as it stands now (http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) we are basically left in the dark; no one knows for sure what does rss, heapused and heaptotal represent.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing what your app is doing, it is impossible to comment on this.

If the V8 heap usage is significantly lower than the RSS, then yes, it must be external buffers and other memory used by non-V8 objects.

Can you make some code public?

Comment: Unfortunately not public. So, RSS = Heap + Buffers + C Libraries?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Have you checked `node --v8-options`? Maybe there is a setting in there that will limit the memory usage.

Comment: @EhevuTov I don't really want to limit the memory usage, because that would probably kill the app. I jsut want to know where (and why) this memory is going.

Comment: @JulienGenestoux I'm assuming it's preallocating memory. V8 uses the heap. Heap is relatively expensive to malloc() and dealloc() as needed, so it's preallocated. That's why I say it's probably something you should see about tuning at runtime with `node --v8-options`

Comment: Is there a way to 'see' what are the allocated buffers?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux i've had a similar issue when I hardcoded a for loop that produced closures.

Comment: @EhevuTov That would produce a closure leak inside the v8 heap which can be witnessed by an ever-growing `heapUsed` and v8 snapshot size increasing. However in this case the `heapUsed` remains somewhat static but only `rss` is rising which indicates the leak (if there is one) is not caused directly by JS code but by native memory such as `Buffer`.